# Scaled up ignite nodes are not participating in the existing topology

Tags: ignite

Ignite cluster was running with 3 replicas and having persistence data storage of 80 GB. Backup as one. CPU 3 cores RAM is 6 GB.

Half of the caches are created with Partitioned mode and collocated. One of this cache is loaded with 70% of data. Remaining caches are replicated.

Scaled up the ignite cluster to 5 with 10 GB RAM. All nodes were up and the newly created nodes were not participating in the existing topology.

Observed one node was using more CPU and RAM and other nodes were using very less.

Can you help us to overcome this scenario?

Comment: Are you sure the one node using more than the others is actually a problem?   What was it like before you scaled up?   Can you scale back down and the problems go away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add nodes to a cluster with persistence enabled, you need to adjust the "baseline topology." There are multiple ways, but the easiest is to use the [control.sh script](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/tools/control-script#adding-nodes-to-baseline-topology):

```
./control.sh --baseline add consistentId1,consistentId2 --yes
```

Comment: Thank you Stephen Darlington. I shall try this.

Comment: Nodes were added to the existing topology. Is it possible to achieve this with the .net API igniteInstance.GetCluster().GetBaselineTopology().Add(..) during scale up with both thick and thin clients?

Comment: Or any other way to achieve it without manual intervention.

Comment: Referring ignite document for this and noted that the Autoadjustment has to be enabled  in the cluster to get this done automatically by the cluster.

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to enable autoadjust. It's better to control when data is rebalanced. You can use control.sh or the APIs; they both do the same thing.